# In Active Directory, can you set the password age limit differently for one organizational unit?

Tags: active-directory

The question in the subject line is pretty straightforward, but a little background.

At our company, ActiveDirectory group policy requires all users to change their password after 90 days.

Is it possible to keep this rule for most users, but set a longer maximum age to one specific organizational unit and the units beneath it?

Comment: you need to create the custom policy using the administrator tool to change the default value of password age . Please refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/password-policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All users, regardless of how they're created have their ***`default password expiration age is set max 90 days`***, But it can be extendable or change you need to create a ***`custom policy`*** using the ***[Active Directory Administrative Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-management-vm)*** from a domain joined VM. The Active Directory Administrative Center lets you view, edit, and create resources in a managed domain, including OUs.

Once created the custom policy you can apply to particular OU’s and group of users as well.

> Note: To create a custom password policy in a managed domain, you must
> be signed in to a user account that's a member of the AAD DC
> Administrators group.

[image]

For more information how to apply the same you can refer this ***[MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/password-policy)*** in which it has mentioned in details.